# Не получается установить нулевое расстояние между ячейками

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Делаю кастовый календарь на UICollectionView. Одна ячейка UICollectionViewCell - одна дата в календаре. Я хочу удалить расстояние между ячейками, чтобы было равно 0. Настройки лейаута -

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.width / 7), height: collectionView.frame.width / 7)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}
```

[image: сториборд]

На разных диагоналях, кроме iPhone X, появляется расстояние между ячейками.

[image: issue]

Вот, к примеру, iPhone SE -

[image: SE]

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось найти решение.
В итоге, что получилось:
1.Из сториборда я убрал trailing и leading констреинты, относящиеся к CalendarView.
2. Установил center horizontally на CalendarView и установил констреинт ширины.
3. В ViewController прокинул оутлет констреинта ширины CalendarView
4. viewDidLoad -

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
let width = self.view.frame.width
let cellSize = CGFloat(width / 7).rounded()
let newWidth = cellSize * 7
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellSize, height: cellSize)
calendarWidth.constant = newWidth
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

И все стало замечательно работать :)

Answer (score 0):

Мне удалось решить аналогичную проблему только путем ручного расчета атрибутов в кастомном классе лейаута, код взят из проекта на Objective C, к сожалению на Swift портировать нет времени, но решение такое же

```
@interface MyCollectionViewFlowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat maximumCellsSpacing;

@end
```

Реализация

```
#import "MyCollectionViewFlowLayout.h"


@implementation MyCollectionViewFlowLayout

- (void)setMaximumCellsSpacing:(CGFloat)maximumCellsSpacing
{
    _maximumCellsSpacing = maximumCellsSpacing;
    self.minimumLineSpacing = maximumCellsSpacing;
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = maximumCellsSpacing;
}

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSArray *initialLayoutAttributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    // Fix for "UICollectionViewFlowLayout has cached frame mismatch for index path..."
    // Make deep copy of attributes https://stackoverflow.com/a/33172179/3004003
    NSArray *layoutAttributes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:initialLayoutAttributes copyItems:YES];

    for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < layoutAttributes.count; ++i) {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *currentLayoutAttributes = layoutAttributes[i];
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *prevLayoutAttributes = layoutAttributes[i - 1];
        CGFloat origin = CGRectGetMaxX(prevLayoutAttributes.frame);

        if (origin + self.maximumCellsSpacing + currentLayoutAttributes.frame.size.width < self.collectionViewContentSize.width && currentLayoutAttributes.frame.origin.x > prevLayoutAttributes.frame.origin.x) {
            CGRect frame = currentLayoutAttributes.frame;
            frame.origin.x = origin + self.maximumCellsSpacing;
            currentLayoutAttributes.frame = frame;
        }
    }

    return layoutAttributes;
}

@end
```

**Дополнение**

Для использования класса его можно указать в сториборд как класс для Collection View Flow Layout, либо назначить программно (`collectionView.collectionViewLayout`) и потом можно использовать свойство `maximumCellsSpacing`

Comment: Привет! Спасибо большое за ответ, я перевел на Swift. Но как использовать эти методы?

Comment: @TheGreatVY см дополнение к ответу

Comment: А для чего используется метод здесь layoutAttributesForElements? Его как-то реализовывать надо?

Comment: @TheGreatVY используется здесь для корректировки положения ячеек, вызывается автоматически, ничего делать не нужно

Comment: Упс, я не заоверрайдил этот метод) Неправильно преобразовал синтаксис.

Comment: Хм. Метод отрабатывает. Но только ничего не изменяется. Не помогло.
        let layout = CalendartCollectionLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth / 7, height: screenWidth / 7)
        layout.setMaximumCellsSpacing(0)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

Comment: @TheGreatVY попробуйте посмотреть во View Debugger ширину ячеек и обшую ширину, а также посмотрите что с расчетами ячеек в `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`, из-за чего могут быть зазоры

Comment: возможно это например из-за погрешностей при делении screenWidth / 7, тогда можно попробовать округлять в большую сторону `ceil(screenWidth / 7)`

Comment: Скорее всего в этом проблема, так как при делении 414 на 7 остается хвост. При округлении последняя дата в неделе уезжает в низ. Сейчас смотрю в сторону внахлест (overlap). Но пока дельного ничего не могу сделать

Comment: @TheGreatVY посмотрите еще что тут получается `currentLayoutAttributes.frame = frame`

Comment: Привет! Я смог пофиксить это. Смотри мой ответ

Comment: @TheGreatVY рад что нашли решение